# Prune duplicate entries from PATH variable

Tags: bash, shell, path, bashrc

I modify my .bashrc frequently and then source it. However, when I have things like 
`export PATH="~/bin:~/perl5/bin:$PATH"` in my file, then the `PATH` environment variable grows every time I source the file.

For example, the first time .bashrc is sourced, the `PATH` variable consists of `~/bin:~/perl5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`.

The second time it consists of `~/bin:~/perl5/bin:~/bin:~/perl5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`.

The third time it consists of `~/bin:~/perl5/bin:~/bin:~/perl5/bin:~/bin:~/perl5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`.

Is there a simple way to make it only add anything that isn't already in the PATH?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the pathmunge() function available in most distro's `/etc/profile`:

```
pathmunge () {
if ! echo $PATH | /bin/egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
   if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
      PATH=$PATH:$1
   else
      PATH=$1:$PATH
   fi
fi
}
```

*edit*: For `zsh` users, `typeset -U <variable_name>` will deduplicate path entries.

Comment: Thanks! It's not in `/etc/profile` on Debian Lenny, so I include it in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: Usage: `pathmunge /some/path` will place `/some/path` at the beginning of `$PATH` and `pathmunge /some/path after` will place `/some/path` at the end of `$PATH`

Comment: Cleaner way of doing the check to see if the hew directory exists in the current path, in modern bash shells: `if ! [[ $PATH =~ (^|:)$1($|:) ]] ; then`.

Comment: I wouldn't use this.  If my naive version said PATH=/foo:$PATH that means I want /foo to win.  `pathmunge /foo before` doesn't accomplish that.  A better way would be to add /foo at the beginning and then remove duplicates afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue so I used a combination of techniques listed on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/bash-split-string-into-array) question.  The following is what I used to dedupe the actual PATH variable that had already been set, since I didn't want to modify the base script.

```
    tmppath=(${PATH// /@})
    array=(${tmppath//:/ })
    for i in "${array[@]//@/ }"
    do
        if ! [[ $PATH_NEW =~ "$i" ]]; then
            PATH_NEW="${PATH_NEW}$i:";
        fi
    done;
    PATH="${PATH_NEW%:}"
    export PATH
    unset PATH_NEW
```

You could always optimize this a bit more, but I had extra code in my original to display what was happening to ensure that it was correctly setting the variables.  The other thing to note is that I perform the following

1. replace any SPACE character with an @ character
2. split the array
3. loop through the array
4. replace any @ characters in the element string with a space

This is to ensure that I can handle directories with spaces in (Samba home directories with Active Directory usernames can have spaces!)

Comment: WARNING: This implementation has a major bug!! it will remove `/bin` if there are other entries like `/usr/bin` because the regexp matches even though the two entries are not the same!

Comment: Here is an alternative implementation that fixes that bug: https://github.com/sukima/dotfiles/blob/92c4ac5842827fd1256c8517c6794288082c0e7d/tools#L115-L128

Answer (score 1):

Set your path explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried setting the path explicitly, but I have a .bashrc file that I use in multiple environments, so the exact default `PATH` is not always the same.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two different ways you could resolve this.  The first one, is to start your .bashrc with a line that explicitly sets your base PATH, that way every time you source it, it is reset to the base prior to adding additional directories.

For example, add:

```
# Reset the PATH to prevent duplication and to make sure that we include
# everything we want.
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Alternately, you can check for an item before you add it to the path.  To do that, you'd use something like:

```
if ! [[ $PATH =~ '~/perl5/bin' ]]
then
    PATH="~/perl5/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

The latter tends to get a little repetitive if you're adding a lot of entries, however, so I tend to stick with the former.  If you wanted to use this and planned on adding a lot of entries, writing a bash function to handle it would be wise.

Note: The second option may only work as written in modern versions bash.  The regular expression support is not a Bourne Shell (/bin/sh) feature, and may not exist in other shells.  Also, the use of quotes may not be needed or may even cause problems on some newest versions of bash.

Comment: Thanks. I tried setting the path explicitly, but I have a .bashrc file that I use in multiple environments, so the exact default `PATH` is not always the same.

Comment: You can still handle that by checking in the script to see what your local hostname is, and then setting your absolute path appropriately for that server.

Comment: Just a typo: the ! is missing in the `if`.  Also, it's surprisingly (to me) easy to make this into a function which loops over space-separated arguments, so you can just say: `add_to_PATH ~/perl5/bin ~/.bin` http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4973/28760 (I guess the `case` statement used there is more portable, but your `if` is clearer to me). *EDIT* weird coincidence that that question also adds perl5!

Comment: @13ren : Thanks for the note.  I also just realized I used single quotes in the PATH set line, instead of double-quotes like I should have.  As written, it would have replaced your existing path with the variable name.  Oops!  Apparently that was a bad entry for me for typos; both are fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Only one string:

```
for i in $(echo $PATH|tr ":" "\n"|sort|uniq);do PATH_NEW="${PATH_NEW}$i:";done;PATH="${PATH_NEW%:}"
```

Comment: Thanks. One difficultly this would cause me is that it alphabetically (or ASCIIbetically) reorders the contents of `$PATH`. I like to put specific directories at the beginning of `$PATH` (like `/home/username`) so that my personal copies of executables are run instead of the built-in defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: 
`PATH=$(echo -n $PATH | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '!x[$0]++' | sed "s/\(.*\).\{1\}/\1/")`

A nice easy one liner that does not leave a trailing :